# 2 different users with different ssh connection options

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ssh

I'm trying to create 2 different users on my EC2 instance, and every user will have a different access option.

The first user can enter with key pair and the second user will connect with a password and MFA.
somehow I can't do it when I'm trying to connect with the key-pair to the second user it asks me for a password.
I added to the `/etc/sudoers`

> ALL=(ALL:ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL

and it asks me for a password.
Does anyone know how to do it that I can have for every user different connection way?

Answer (score 0):

As for the user which needs to access with `key-pair` only, you need to add something like the following in your `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` file.

```
Match User $user
PasswordAuthentication no
PubkeyAuthentication yes
AuthorizedKeysCommand /usr/bin/sss_ssh_authorizedkeys
AuthorizedKeysCommandUser nobody
AuthenticationMethods "publickey"
```

As for the user with `MFA`, I don't think you can do it on ssh level. MFA has nothign to do with ssh or in this case your system.
You can change `AuthenticationMethods "publickey"` to `AuthenticationMethods "password"` for the second user.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
I succeeded to enable MFA with google authenticator on the user with the password.
from what I understand in the sshd_config file I just need to separate users by "Match User $user"

Comment: yes, but I still don't understand how can you deny ssh access via IAM to an instance..?

Comment: I don't want to deny, 1 of the users will not get the key and the access will be only via password (not because deny just because he will don't have the key)